# Meteor and Data Binding

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Assume you have a list of items from an object array onRendered. Your list items are buttons with specific css. When you click the button you choose an item to be selected, the button changes its class using jQuery. So, now you grant the user to search within another array and show the results using the same helper function. The result is, you click the first button inside the list and when you start the search the first element of the visible element is always selected because the css value is this there. Meteor only displays data and does not actually render this list again. How can I get rid of the selected button without using jQuery. Any idea?

[image: List with selected button]
List with selected button

[image: Result list after search with button that is still selected]
Result list after search with button that is still selected

```js
Template['brands'].events({
'keyup #brand-filter': function (e,t) {
    var search:string = $(e.target).val().toLowerCase(),
        liveBrands = LIVEBRANDS.brands || {},
        returnBrands = [];

    if(search.length > 0)
    {
        var searchRegex = new RegExp('^' + search.toLowerCase(), 'i');

        // iterate over each element in the array
        for (var i = 0; i < LIVEBRANDS.brands.length; i++){
            // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
            if(searchRegex.test(LIVEBRANDS.brands[i].name))
            {
                returnBrands.push(_.extend(liveBrands[i],{"shortName":"b"}));
            }
        }

        Session.set('collection',returnBrands);
    }
    else
    {
        Session.set('collection',originBrandsArry);
    }
}});
```

```html
<template name="ob_brands">
<div class="modal-content flow-text">

    {{>order_card data=data}}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l12 m12 s12 center">
            {{>ob_title data=data}}
        </div>
        <p class="col l3 m3 s3">&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="col l6 m6 s6 brand-search input-field">
            <i class="ion-ios-search-strong prefix"></i>
            <input id="brand-filter" type="text" placeholder="Brands.."/>
        </div>
        <p class="col l3 m3 s3">&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="col l12 m12 s12 center">
            <!--This part is what I am looking for-->
            {{#each brands}}
                <a class="btn btn-flat active" data-name="{{this.name}}" data-id="{{this.shortName}}{{this.id}}" href="#{{this.id}}">{{this.name}}</a>
            {{/each}}
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

</div>
```

Comment: could you please show the code that you use to show the list and select buttons? It's hard to guess how to get this done without seeing the code/

Comment: Just added some code.

Comment: Ideally your selected buttons class is reactive. You want to avoid jquery to keep your coding simple. Spacebars only displays html attributes if a value exists. So, for example, add .active to your brands object. Each time someone clicks a brand, update your reactive variable (or collection) to set each brands.active to "" and immediately after update the clicked brand in your collection to brands.active:"active". If you want a more specific example with code I can write an answer but maybe this gets you started.

Comment: You gave me a good start, I decided to build a "manager" with reactive variables. Thanks!